# Throw exception without halting execution?

Tags: php, mysql, exception

I've dug myself into a bit of a hole with the project I'm working on. I've got this massive project (100s of thousands of lines), and there are MySQL errors everywhere. I'm in the process of cleaning them up now.

I've got this database class which all the queries go through, so what I've done is whenever there is an SQL error, I throw an exception now. The problem is that I can't have the execution stop. It has to continue as it always had, and just log the exception so I can track them down and fix them one at a time.

I was hoping `set_exception_handler` would do what I want, but the docs specifically say it will halt execution after calling my handler. So how do I get around this?

The exception can halt the current function, but then I want it to drop out of the function, perhaps returning null or false, and then continue as normal, but I need it to call my global exception handler.

---

To clarify:

I want to throw an exception from my database class (whenever there is an SQL error). I then want to log this error and/or display a message on screen until I can either fix the SQL error, or wrap the offending line in a try/catch. I don't want it to halt execution. If I simply call some `error_handler()` function rather than throwing an exception, then I can't catch it. If I catch it immediately (also within the DB class), then I can't catch it further down the stack (unless I re-throw it, but then we're back to halting execution).

Comment: If you've already updated the code to translate MySQL errors into exceptions why not just log the error instead of throw an exception?

Comment: @pgraham: Darn it... that's a good question. The reason is because I wanted to be able to catch the exception if I didn't want it to fall to the global exception handler. Plus, I want a centralized exception handling and logging function. Lastly, once I clean the errors out, I want to modify the global exception handler slightly so that it actually *does* die and throw a fatal error.

Comment: @downvoter: Care to explain why this is a bad question?

Comment: I don't want to be sound obnoxious or anything, but it looks like you're not familiar with how exceptions work (stripping the frames from the stack, loosing your current env variables values etc). What you want to do is just add a debug printing like @pgraham commented here - and like I commented on the answer you posted and deleted. I think that your question will confuse more than help other people. So I chose to downvote.

Comment: @alfasin: 1) I deleted my post because I realize it didn't make sense after pgraham posed the question above, 2) The question itself isn't meant to enlighten anyone, that's why it's a question. If you think it's a bad idea, post why as an answer so that it *can* help them. Downvoting a question for mistaken beliefs could prevent other people with my same wrong-thinking from learning. 3) I had debug printing. I want exceptions so that they'll be catchable (as explained in comment above).

Comment: Plus, they *should* be exceptions. An SQL error is an error, my project just isn't at a state where blowing up is acceptable. I'm trying to compromise by creating a stop gap until I can finish cleaning up the errors.

Comment: Short answer then is no.  If you can't wrap all code in try/catch blocks, then anything that reaches the top level exception handler is going to die.  My recommendation would be to define a logging function to which you can pass an exception.  Then instead of throwing the exception when you translate MySQL errors to exceptions, pass it to the logging function.  Later when you do want the fatal error, you only need to update the logging function to also throw the exception.

Comment: @pgraham: Yeah, that's exactly what I was doing for a bit, but it seemed kinda hacky, so I starting using `trigger_error` instead with `E_USER_WARNING`, and then later if I want to up the severity I can change it to `E_USER_ERROR`. More or less the same result though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you correctly:

```
function myFunction($params) {

    try {

        //your code which throws Exception

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        myErrorFunction($e);
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: No, I don't think you understand my full requirements. Where would I put the try/catch? I don't have time right now to put it around every single SQL query, so I'd have to put it exactly where I throw it...but then I can't catch it further down because I've already caught it. I don't think what I want to do is possible.

Comment: You can wrap either the entire code or just use it in your database class. How many methods do you have? 10? 20? Just wrap them with that try catch and every time you execute it, for example `$db->myCustonQuery()`, you know that if an error occurs it will throw an exception that you can handle somewhere else. The real point of this answer is that if you `return false` you'll be able to continue your execution.

Comment: If I wrap the entire code, then when an exception is thrown, execution will drop to that point (the catch); I need it to continue pretty much where it left off (at the throw). How many methods? What, in my DB class? 10-20 is a reasonable estimate, but wrapping those doesn't let me catch it where I want either. Basically I want to *be able* to catch at where I call `$db->GetSingleRecord()`, but optionally, because there are thousands of calls to said function and I have to go through them all. Does that make sense? I think what I'm asking is unrealistic, but that would be the optimal case.

Comment: Time constraints aside, it really sounds like you need to refactor the whole thing.

Comment: @Ing: I'd love to. Unfortunately, time constraints are a real thing that can't be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a workaround. Instead of *throwing* an exception, I can call my handler directly with the exception:

```
global_exception_handler(new MySqlException($error_message));
```

That way my handler still gets called, but execution continues.

And then that same exception handler can still be used to catch all the other exceptions that actually are thrown:

```
function _global_exception_handler($e) {
    // log error here
}

set_exception_handler('global_exception_handler');
```

Comment: that's kind of like adding a debug printing, no?

Answer (score 0):

Old post I know but I asked this question too and found out the answer was to add this line at the top where you're using try catch(Exception):

> use Exception;